Sorting tables in Word based on order set in Excel sheet 2
I've tables in Word, which I want to sort based on the order set in Excel sheet 2 column 1.
Column 1 of Excel and Word tables have the same matches, and I want to sort Word tables based on the order in Excel.
I'm getting issues continuously, the issue which I'm now getting is "No match found for Word text: 'Word'.
The tables I'm working with has first row as Parts Required.
Please review the code If anyone has the solution for this, I'd highly appreciate.
Sub RearrangeWordTableRowsBasedOnExcel()

    Dim wordTable As Table
    Dim wordRow As Row
    Dim wordText As String
    Dim excelApp As Object
    Dim excelWorkbook As Object
    Dim excelSheet As Object
    Dim excelRange As Object
    Dim matchRow As Long
    Dim wordDoc As Document
    Dim userExcelFile As Variant
    Dim sheetName As String
    Dim sheetExists As Boolean
    Dim targetRow As Long
    Dim excelText As String
    Dim foundTable As Boolean
    foundTable = False
    
    ' Create an instance of Excel Application
    Set excelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    
    ' Ask user to select the Excel file
    userExcelFile = excelApp.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xls; *.xlsx), *.xls; *.xlsx", , "Select Excel File")
    
    ' Exit if no file selected
    If userExcelFile = False Then
        MsgBox "No file selected. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Open the selected Excel file
    Set excelWorkbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(userExcelFile)
    
    ' Check if "Sheet2" exists in the workbook
    sheetName = "Sheet2" ' Modify this name if necessary
    On Error Resume Next
    Set excelSheet = excelWorkbook.Sheets(sheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0
    
    If excelSheet Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Sheet2 does not exist in the selected Excel file. Exiting."
        excelWorkbook.Close False
        excelApp.Quit
        Set excelSheet = Nothing
        Set excelWorkbook = Nothing
        Set excelApp = Nothing
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Set Word document
    Set wordDoc = ActiveDocument
    
    ' Loop through the tables in the Word document
    For Each wordTable In wordDoc.Tables
        ' Check if the first cell in the first row contains "Parts Required"
        If wordTable.cell(1, 1).Range.text Like "*Parts Required*" Then
            ' Found the correct table
            foundTable = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next wordTable
    
    ' If no table with "Parts Required" is found, exit
    If Not foundTable Then
        MsgBox "No table with 'Parts Required' found in the Word document. Exiting."
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Loop through the rows in the found Word table starting from row 3 (index 3)
    For Each wordRow In wordTable.Rows
        If wordRow.Index >= 3 Then ' Start from row 3
            wordText = wordRow.Cells(1).Range.text
            wordText = Left(wordText, Len(wordText) - 2) ' Remove end of cell markers (Chr(13) and Chr(7))
            wordText = CleanText(wordText) ' Clean Word text
            
            ' Debugging: Show Word text details and character codes
            Debug.Print "Word Text (Before Clean): '" & wordRow.Cells(1).Range.text & "'"
            Debug.Print "Word Text (After Clean): '" & wordText & "'"
            Debug.Print "Word Text (Character Codes): " & GetCharacterCodes(wordText)
            
            ' Skip if Word row is empty
            If Len(wordText) = 0 Then
                Debug.Print "Skipping empty Word row."
                GoTo SkipRow
            End If
            
            ' Find the match in Excel (Column 1)
            On Error Resume Next ' Ignore errors temporarily
            Set excelRange = excelSheet.Range("A:A").Find(wordText, , xlValues, xlWhole)
            On Error GoTo 0 ' Turn off error ignoring
            
            ' Debugging: Show Excel value being compared
            If Not excelRange Is Nothing Then
                Debug.Print "Excel Row (" & excelRange.Row & "): " & excelRange.Value
                
                ' Clean the Excel text
                excelText = CleanText(excelRange.Value)
                
                ' Debugging: Show cleaned Excel text and character codes
                Debug.Print "Excel Text (Cleaned): '" & excelText & "'"
                Debug.Print "Excel Text (Character Codes): " & GetCharacterCodes(excelText)
                
                ' Compare Word and Excel texts (strict and fuzzy)
                If StrComp(LCase(wordText), LCase(excelText), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then ' Case insensitive comparison
                    MsgBox "Exact Match found for '" & wordText & "' in Excel at row " & excelRange.Row & " with text: '" & excelText & "'"
                    
                    ' Calculate the target row in Word (Excel's row number minus 1)
                    targetRow = excelRange.Row
                    
                    ' Ensure the target row is within the bounds of the Word table
                    If targetRow <= wordTable.Rows.Count Then
                        ' Move the Word row to the corresponding row in Excel
                        If targetRow <> wordRow.Index Then
                            MsgBox "Moving Word row " & wordRow.Index & " to target row " & targetRow
                            wordTable.Rows(wordRow.Index).Range.Cut ' Cut the row from Word
                            wordTable.Rows(targetRow).Range.InsertBefore wordRow.Range ' Insert the row at the target position
                            wordRow.Delete ' Delete the original row after moving
                        End If
                    Else
                        MsgBox "Target row " & targetRow & " is out of bounds for the Word table."
                    End If
                Else
                    MsgBox "No Exact Match found for Word text: '" & wordText & "'"
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "No match found for Word text: '" & wordText & "'"
            End If
        End If
SkipRow:
    Next wordRow
    
    ' Clean up Excel
    excelWorkbook.Close False
    excelApp.Quit
    Set excelSheet = Nothing
    Set excelWorkbook = Nothing
    Set excelApp = Nothing
    
    MsgBox "Rows rearranged based on Excel matching."
End Sub

' Function to clean text by removing non-printable characters and trimming spaces
Function CleanText(ByVal text As String) As String
    text = Replace(text, Chr(13), "") ' Remove carriage returns
    text = Replace(text, Chr(7), "") ' Remove bell character
    text = Replace(text, Chr(160), "") ' Remove non-breaking spaces
    text = Trim(text) ' Trim spaces
    text = Replace(text, Chr(9), "") ' Remove tab characters
    CleanText = text
End Function

' Function to return the ASCII codes of characters in a string for debugging
Function GetCharacterCodes(ByVal text As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim charCodes As String
    charCodes = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(text)
        charCodes = charCodes & Asc(Mid(text, i, 1)) & " "
    Next i
    GetCharacterCodes = charCodes
End Function


Are you wanting to sort the order of the tables, or just the content within the tables?
